# Database Backup Failure SQL Server 2012 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, sql-server-job, sql-server-administration

I am running a split disk backup such as:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [At] TO  
DISK = N'O:\sql_bak\At_full1.bak',  
DISK = N'M:\sql_bak\At_full2.bak',
DISK = N'L:\sql_bak\At_full3.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, 
INIT,  
NAME = N'At-Full Database Backup', 
SKIP, 
NOREWIND, 
NOUNLOAD,  
STATS = 10
GO
```

It is failing with the below error:

> Executed as user: DOMAIN\sqlserviceaccount. Processed 257856 pages for
>   database 'At', file 'At' on file 1. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 4035) 
>   10 percent processed. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 3211)  20 percent
>   processed. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 3211)  30 percent processed.
>   [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 3211)  40 percent processed. [SQLSTATE
>   01000] (Message 3211)  50 percent processed. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message
>   3211)  60 percent processed. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 3211)  70
>   percent processed. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 3211)  80 percent
>   processed. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 3211)  Write on
>   "O:\sql_bak\At_full1.bak" failed: 112(There is not enough space on the
>   disk.) [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3202)  BACKUP DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3013).  The step failed.

The database At is of 4TB size and the drives L,M and O are of 2TB each. These drives are completely free. It ran successfully once and since then it has been failing. Please suggest.

Comment: "Drives L, M, and O are 2TB each".  Is that total capacity per drive? Or free space per drive?

Comment: @DMason The drives L, M and O have total capacity = 2TB each and as these are totally free, we have free space = 2TB on each drive.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question (and it is quite interesting), but have you tried using `WITH COMPRESSION`?

Comment: [Trace flag 3042](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396(v=sql.110).aspx) might help you also.

Comment: @DMason the backup was successful after I added the WITH COMPRESSION option. Thanks. But I feel it is just a workaround and not a permanent fix because I am not sure if the backup will succeed once the database size has increased further. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I also consider it a workaround.  The issue warrants further research.  Have you tried trace flag 3042?  I'd be interested to hear your results.  Keep us posted!